# table using json fields in mysql 8 take up unusually more space than actual data

Tags: mysql, diskspace, azure-mysql-database

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `doc` JSON NOT NULL,
    `rev` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `updated_at` (`updated_at`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'm simply using it for storing json data.

The size of the json field increases gradually from at least 15kb to have data within 100kb.

It was confirmed that about 82,317 rows occupied 90 GB.

> ```
> Name: "user_info"
> Engine: "InnoDB"
> Version: 10
> Row_format: "Dynamic"
> Rows: 82317
> Avg_row_length: 1095193
> Data_length: 90153074688
> Max_data_length: 0
> Index_length: 3555328
> Data_free: 40894464
> Auto_increment: null
> Create_time: "2020-05-19 10:56:14"
> Update_time: "2020-08-21 07:30:17"
> Check_time: null
> Collation: "utf8mb4_general_ci"
> Checksum: null
> Create_options: ""
> Comment: ""
> ```

The expected maximum disk usage is 8 GB.

Dump file size is 1.2 GB, and when restored, you are using a 1.9 GB disk.

> ```
> Name: "user_info"
> Engine: "InnoDB"
> Version: 10
> Row_format: "Dynamic"
> Rows: 84626
> Avg_row_length: 22770
> Data_length: 1926987776
> Max_data_length: 0
> Index_length: 3686400
> Data_free: 14680064
> Auto_increment: null
> Create_time: "2020-08-21 07:59:34"
> Update_time: "2020-08-21 08:02:05"
> Check_time: null
> Collation: "utf8mb4_general_ci"
> Checksum: null
> Create_options: ""
> Comment: "
> ```

I suspect that the json field is causing database fragmentation.

I would like to ask if you have similar experience.

Currently I'm looking at how to allocate a field with a fixed length of around 200kb.

> ```
> session_variables
> ---
> | Variable_name                            | Value                         | 
> | ---                                      | ---                           | 
> | innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                            | 
> | innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                            | 
> | innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                            | 
> | innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                             | 
> | innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                        | 
> | innodb_aggressive_pc                     | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_aio_write_slots                   | 32                            | 
> | innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                             | 
> | innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                             | 
> | innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                            | 
> | innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 1                             | 
> | innodb_avoid_logwrite                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 67108864                      | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                            | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool                | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file          | ON                            | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 8                             | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 3758096384                    | 
> | innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                            | 
> | innodb_change_buffering                  | all                           | 
> | innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                         | 
> | innodb_chunk_write_enabled               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                             | 
> | innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                             | 
> | innodb_compression_level                 | 6                             | 
> | innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                            | 
> | innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                          | 
> | innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend        | 
> | innodb_data_home_dir                     |                               | 
> | innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                            | 
> | innodb_dedicated_server                  | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                       | 
> | innodb_delay_datasync                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_delay_logwrite                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_directories                       |                               | 
> | innodb_dirty_page_fflush                 | 10                            | 
> | innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_diskfull_wa_enabled               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_doublewrite                       | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_dynamic_page_cleaners             | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_fast0ext_enabled                  | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                             | 
> | innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold    | 600                           | 
> | innodb_file_per_table                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_filesize_update_interval          | 0                             | 
> | innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                           | 
> | innodb_flush_data_file_before_checkpoint | ON                            | 
> | innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                             | 
> | innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 1                             | 
> | innodb_flush_log_checkpoint              | ON                            | 
> | innodb_flush_method                      | unbuffered                    | 
> | innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 0                             | 
> | innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                            | 
> | innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                            | 
> | innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_force_pacing                      | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                             | 
> | innodb_fs_block_size                     | 8192                          | 
> | innodb_fsync_threshold                   | 0                             | 
> | innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                               | 
> | innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                       | 
> | innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                            | 
> | innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                            | 
> | innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                             | 
> | innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                          | 
> | innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000                    | 
> | innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                               | 
> | innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                             | 
> | innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000                     | 
> | innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                               | 
> | innodb_harness_checkpoint                | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_ignore_fsctl_set_sparse           | ON                            | 
> | innodb_ignore_fsctl_set_zero_data        | ON                            | 
> | innodb_inflight_syncio                   | 100                           | 
> | innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                           | 
> | innodb_io_capacity_calibceil             | 300                           | 
> | innodb_io_capacity_calibrate             | 0                             | 
> | innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                          | 
> | innodb_io_hosed_threshold                | 2048000                       | 
> | innodb_io_throttled_threshold            | 2048000                       | 
> | innodb_list_dir_files_name_only          | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                            | 
> | innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 16777216                      | 
> | innodb_log_checkpoint_every              | 1000                          | 
> | innodb_log_checksums                     | ON                            | 
> | innodb_log_closer_spin_delay             | 0                             | 
> | innodb_log_closer_timeout                | 1000                          | 
> | innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                            | 
> | innodb_log_file_size                     | 268435456                     | 
> | innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                             | 
> | innodb_log_flush_events                  | 2048                          | 
> | innodb_log_flush_notifier_spin_delay     | 0                             | 
> | innodb_log_flush_notifier_timeout        | 10                            | 
> | innodb_log_flusher_spin_delay            | 250000                        | 
> | innodb_log_flusher_timeout               | 10                            | 
> | innodb_log_group_home_dir                | .\                            | 
> | innodb_log_recent_closed_size            | 2097152                       | 
> | innodb_log_recent_written_size           | 1048576                       | 
> | innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm              | 80                            | 
> | innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm              | 50                            | 
> | innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_delay     | 25000                         | 
> | innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm       | 400                           | 
> | innodb_log_wait_for_flush_timeout        | 1000                          | 
> | innodb_log_wait_for_write_spin_delay     | 25000                         | 
> | innodb_log_wait_for_write_timeout        | 1000                          | 
> | innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                          | 
> | innodb_log_write_backoff                 | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_log_write_events                  | 2048                          | 
> | innodb_log_write_max_size                | 4096                          | 
> | innodb_log_write_notifier_spin_delay     | 0                             | 
> | innodb_log_write_notifier_timeout        | 10                            | 
> | innodb_log_writer_spin_delay             | 250000                        | 
> | innodb_log_writer_timeout                | 10                            | 
> | innodb_logwr_prio_checkpoint             | 0                             | 
> | innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                          | 
> | innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 90.000000                     | 
> | innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 10.000000                     | 
> | innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                             | 
> | innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                             | 
> | innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824                    | 
> | innodb_min_tsc_freq                      | 2000                          | 
> | innodb_monitor_disable                   |                               | 
> | innodb_monitor_enable                    |                               | 
> | innodb_monitor_reset                     |                               | 
> | innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                               | 
> | innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                            | 
> | innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                          | 
> | innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728                     | 
> | innodb_open_files                        | 300                           | 
> | innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_page_cleaner_priority             | 0                             | 
> | innodb_page_cleaners                     | 4                             | 
> | innodb_page_cleaners_enforced            | 4                             | 
> | innodb_page_size                         | 16384                         | 
> | innodb_parallel_read_threads             | 4                             | 
> | innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_print_ddl_logs                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                           | 
> | innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                           | 
> | innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                             | 
> | innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                            | 
> | innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                             | 
> | innodb_read_io_threads_enforced          | 4                             | 
> | innodb_read_only                         | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_read_throttle_hint                | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_redo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                             | 
> | innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                           | 
> | innodb_skip_check_ibd                    | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                       | 
> | innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                             | 
> | innodb_standalone_systmp                 | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                            | 
> | innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal                   | 
> | innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                            | 
> | innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                            | 
> | innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                             | 
> | innodb_status_output                     | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                            | 
> | innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                             | 
> | innodb_sync_log_slots                    | 0                             | 
> | innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                            | 
> | innodb_table_locks                       | ON                            | 
> | innodb_temp_data_file_path               | C:\temp\ibtmp1:12M:autoextend | 
> | innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir              | C:\temp\                      | 
> | innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                             | 
> | innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                         | 
> | innodb_tmpdir                            | C:\temp                       | 
> | innodb_undo_directory                    | .\                            | 
> | innodb_undo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | ON                            | 
> | innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 2                             | 
> | innodb_use_enforced                      | OFF                           | 
> | innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                            | 
> | innodb_version                           | 8.0.15                        | 
> | innodb_write_io_threads                  | 4                             | 
> | innodb_write_io_threads_enforced         | 4                             | 
> | innodb_write_throttle_hint               | OFF                           |
> ```

Comment: can u  try  max_allowed_packetsize

Comment: you  can  try  JSON_STORAGE_SIZE(),JSON_STORAGE_FREE()  functions

Comment: @SivaKoteswaraRao checked results. SUM(JSON_STORAGE_SIZE(doc)) = 1272057191 bytes (1.2 GB) SUM(JSON_STORAGE_FREE) = 0 bytes, max_allowed_packet = 536870912 bytes (500 MB).
It is a difficult situation for me to understand.